# Merge 2 CSV Files into one CSV File

Tags: c#, csv

I need to merge two CSV Files into one.

As example: CSV_FileOne

```
Key;Dutch
ERROR_LicenseNotFound;Error de licensie kan niet gevonden worden.
ERROR_LicenseIsEmpty;Error de licensiefile is leeg.
```

CSV_FileTwo

```
Key;Deutsch
ERROR_LicenseNotFound;Fehler die Lizenz kann nicht gefunden werden.
ERROR_LicenseIsEmpty;Fehler die Lizenzdatei ist leer.
```

So the result shoud be:

```
Key;Dutch;Deutsch
ERROR_LicenseNotFound;Error de licensie kan niet gevonden worden.;Fehler die Lizenz kann nicht gefunden werden.
ERROR_LicenseIsEmpty;Error de licensiefile is leeg.;Fehler die Lizenzdatei ist leer.
```

I have to do this, because I am making a Program for a Dutch company.

I hop you can help me.

Comment: Welcome. Can you show us what you've already tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: is line 2 of your expected result necessary?

Comment: @imsmn
I don't have any ideas how I could do it. But what I have already done, is a Grid (with Windows Forms) where you can put in .CSV Files. But i need 3 columns and not 2.

Comment: @JSGarcia Yes. Of Course. Those files are translations files. It's better to translate with context than without.

Comment: of course. but line 2: `Key;Dutch` looks like a second header with the declared fields being exaclty the same as declared in the first header.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. That's wrong. I'll edit the post. There's only one header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load your files, that you want combined into memory and then create the output file on your own:

```
using System.IO;

// reading both csv files into memory
string[] left = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile1);
string[] right = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile2);

// opening stream + streamwriter
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Create))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < left.Length; i++)
    {
        // in each line we take the entire line of left and append field 1 of right
        sw.WriteLine(left[i] + ";" + right[i].Split(';')[1];);
    }
    
}
```

please bear in mind: this is a quick and dirty solution. it expects that both files have the exact same order of keys. you could create a dictionary and associate the strings trough the key to get a more robust method but I'll leave some work for you to do

Comment: YES you did it. Thank you.

Comment: This answer was helpful,